# MySQL : Multiple where clauses for detecting between month and year of given dates

Tags: php, mysql

I've dug through tons of questions on here not finding a close enough sample of SQL to get the information that I need.  I'm using MYSQL and PHP to keep track of special hours and events in a calendar situation.  I have the month and the year that I want to get a specific bit of information from the db and everything I try isn't working.  I haven't been keeping track of everything I have tried so far, but it has been a lot.  I don't want to add a date into the test, because I want to look at each month individually and not have to do a separate query for each day.

## Current SQL

```sql
 SELECT *
    FROM LiveSpecialHours
        LEFT JOIN Libraries
            ON LibraryID = Libraries.id
        LEFT JOIN LibraryDepartment
            ON DepartmentID = LibraryDepartment.ldId
    WHERE (YEAR(2015-07-01) BETWEEN YEAR(startDate) AND YEAR(endDate))
    AND   (MONTH(2015-07-01) BETWEEN MONTH(startDate) AND MONTH(endDate));
```

Comment: if "current" means "actual", then `(2015-07-01)` will fail. MySQL thinks you want to substract/math. Do `('2015-07-01')` wrap those in quotes.

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple of a mistake that I had been fighting with for the past hours!  Thanks for the help it worked perfectly. Thanks @Fred-ii-

Comment: you're welcome David.

Comment: You want to put that as an answer so I can give you the checkmark.

Comment: coming right up, just formulating a proper answer now. Won't be long David.

Comment: It has been done David, *cheers*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting my comment to an answer, as requested.

If "current" means "actual", then `(2015-07-01)` will fail. MySQL thinks you want to substract/math.

Do `('2015-07-01')` wrap those in quotes rendering it as a string literal, rather than a mathematical problem (2015 minus 07 minus 01).

- Ref: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-literals.html

Check for errors, depending on which MySQL API you are using to connect/query with, if done through PHP.

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php - PDO
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php - MySQLi_
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php - MySQL_

It would have signaled the syntax error.

Sidenote:

It would have thrown a syntax error through phpmyadmin also (as an example interface), if you're not querying through PHP.

Comment: I was doing it through command line in a vagrant box until the tests come out with results.  It said there were warnings, but I could get the warning to display an actual code or what the warning was in the statement.

Comment: @DavidJ.Davis if you have server logs enabled to write to, they'd be in there, well.. chances are anyway ;-)